# Find the path to the main artifact in a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I'm developing a Maven plugin to automatically install the JAR on a server. The first step for me should be to find the compiled JAR and move it to the server, but how do I find my JAR?

My first attempt was:

```
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        String workingPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File targetDir = new File(workingPath + File.separatorChar + "target");

        for (File f : targetDir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".jar") {
                System.out.println("Found jar " + f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use a fixed directory "target". Is there any way to know where the jar will be built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the simple way to do this is to inject the [`MavenProject`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) that is currently being built, and retrieve the file corresponding to its artifact, as returned by [`getArtifact()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifact()). This works whatever the packaging of the project (`jar`, `war`, etc.), or where the artifact was actually generated.

```
@Mojo(name = "foo")
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        // this is the main artifact file
        File file = project.getArtifact().getFile();
        getLog().info(file.toString());
    }

}
```

This declares the goal called `"foo"`. It is injected the value `${project}`, which is evaluated to the current Maven project by the [`PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html).

Your Maven plugin will need to have a dependency on [`maven-plugin-annotations`](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/) (for the [`@Parameter`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html) and [`@Mojo`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools-archives/plugin-tools-3.5/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Mojo.html) annotation), and on `maven-core` for the `MavenProject`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Of course, this requires that the artifact for the project was actually built, which is to say that the plugin has to run after the `package` phase; otherwise there is no file to the artifact.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. and as you said in your comment, I didn't want to use a fixed directory because the outputDirectory could easily be defined differently

Answer (score 1):

You could use the value of the [**predefined variables**](https://github.com/cko/predefined_maven_properties/blob/master/README.md) `project.build.directory`, `project.build.finalName` and `project.packaging` to build the path of your archive as **default value** of a parameter of your plugin, something like:

```
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"
     */
    private String archivePath;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        File archive = new File(archivePath);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only part of the solution; the final name of the artifact, and its packaging, still needs to be retrieved.

Comment: And it actually doesn't work for all cases, because the user could set a custom [`outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) to the JAR Plugin, different than the build directory.

Comment: Last note, the Javadoc annotations for plugin parameters is the old Maven 2 way of doing it. Java annotations are prefered for Maven 3 (and above).